# Jquery remove and add new class in list

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new here. So maybe this is a silly question. I have a CSS code below:

```
 <ul id="nav">
  <li><h1>Cover</h1><a class="cover" href="#cover"></a></li>
  <li><h1>About</h1><a class="about" href="#about"></a></li>
  <li><h1>CV</h1><a class="cv" href="#cv"></a></li>
  <li><h1>Contact</h1><a class="contact" href="#contact"></a></li>
 </ul>
```

So now when I click to "About", the class "about" will be changed to "active". Similiar with other rows. And how to avoid duplicate the class "active"?

My jQuery code below but nothing happens:

```
$('#nav.about a').click(function() {
   $('#nav.about a').removeClass('about').addClass('active');
});
```

Thanks in advance for any helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, the selector `#nav.about a` looks for an `a` element that's a child of an element with both the `id` of `nav` *and* the `class` of `about`. For your HTML, you're looking for: `#nav a.about'`; giving the jQuery:

```
$('#nav a.about').click(function() {
   $(this).removeClass('about').addClass('active');
});
```

With regards to the question added, in the comments (below):

> [How to avoid the class "active" which is selected many times? ...when I clicked "About", this class set to "active"; also when I clicked "Contact", this class set to "active" too. So I want to limit only one "active" class at same time.

To achieve this, simply select the element(s) with that class-name within the `click()` method, as below:

```
$('#nav a.about').click(function() {
   $('#nav a.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).removeClass('about').addClass('active');
});
```

References:

- [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/).

Comment: it's great. thanks so much! another question: how to avoid the class "active" which is selected many times?

Comment: Can you explain your question? I'm not sure I understand what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry for my English. Eg: when I clicked "About", this class set to "active"; also when I clicked "Contact", this class set to "active" too. So I want to limit only one "active" class at same time.

Comment: See the edit, I think that should address the problem you're facing.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works like a charm :-) I'm graphic designer so let me know if you want some help :-) Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

change `$('#nav.about a')` to `$('#nav a.about')`

```
$('#nav.about a').click(function() {
   $('#nav a.about').removeClass('about').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your selector. What you have is saying find me an anchor element that is a descendant of an element with ID `nav` AND class `about`". What you want is below, which says "find me an anchor tag with class `about` that is a descendant of the element with ID `nav`:

```
$('#nav a.about').click(function() {
   $(this).removeClass('about').addClass('active');
});
```